# Difference between Card lock and Global lock privilege in Global Platform

Tags: smartcard, globalplatform

What is the core difference between card lock and Global lock privilege in Global Platform? If not, then why we need two privileges?

Can an application with Global lock privilege lock card as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

The first difference to understand is the difference between the Card Life Cycle States and Application and Security Domain Life Cycle.

The Card Lock Privilege is used to change the Card life Cycle to Locked state and either the OPEN, or a Security Domain with Card Lock privilege, or an Application with Card Lock
privilege , may initiate the transition from the state SECURED to the state
CARD_LOCKED.

and

A Security Domain or Application with Global Lock privilege is only able to change the life cycle of the SD and Application (independent of its Security Domain association and hierarchy) not the Card Life Cycle from the following states to locked
INSTALLED
SELECTABLE
PERSONALIZED

Regards